# Groupby ID pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like:

```
ID,"address","used_at","active_seconds","pageviews"
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 18:14:58,57,4
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 20:11:15,1884,90
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-10-04 09:44:21,1146,6
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"avito.ru",2014-09-29 21:01:29,48,3
```

I have only date with `2014` and `2015` year.

I want to group by `address` and get the number of users to every year to every website, but I have an error

```
print(DataFrame({'count' : infile.groupby(["address", infile['used_at'].dt.year].ID.nunique())}))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ID'
```

I try to rename my column

```
infile = pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[2], low_memory=False, names=['user', 'address', 'date', 'duration', 'unknown'] )
```

But i have no result. Because last name isn't disappear.

How can I do this group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for creating `DataFrame` for creating number of unique users (`ID`) by [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
infile = pd.read_csv("test/avito_trend.csv", 
                      parse_dates=[2])


print (infile.groupby(["address",infile['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].nunique()
                                                                  .reset_index(name='count'))
              address  used_at  count
0               am.ru     2014    621
1               am.ru     2015    273
2             auto.ru     2014   1752
3             auto.ru     2015   1595
4            avito.ru     2014   5460
5            avito.ru     2015   4631
6       avtomarket.ru     2014    314
7       avtomarket.ru     2015    215
8   cars.mail.ru/sale     2014    457
9   cars.mail.ru/sale     2015    271
10            drom.ru     2014   1934
11            drom.ru     2015   1623
12              e1.ru     2014   1654
13              e1.ru     2015   1359
14        irr.ru/cars     2014    619
15        irr.ru/cars     2015    426
```

Or if you need number of all users use [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
print (infile.groupby(["address",infile['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].count()
                                                                  .reset_index(name='count'))

              address  used_at   count
0               am.ru     2014    1422
1               am.ru     2015     867
2             auto.ru     2014   14670
3             auto.ru     2015   13237
4            avito.ru     2014  150240
5            avito.ru     2015  145915
6       avtomarket.ru     2014     648
7       avtomarket.ru     2015     681
8   cars.mail.ru/sale     2014    1211
9   cars.mail.ru/sale     2015     726
10            drom.ru     2014   18678
11            drom.ru     2015   16194
12              e1.ru     2014   64426
13              e1.ru     2015   67164
14        irr.ru/cars     2014    1472
15        irr.ru/cars     2015     878
```

Comment: I have an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`. It's count, but doesn't give name `count`

Comment: Interestnig, for me it work very well. What version of `pandas` use? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: version pandas 0.18.0

Comment: but that `print(infile.groupby(["address", infile['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].count().reset_index(name='count'))` works

Comment: I think it is problem you use `python 3`, right? Because I use python `2.7.10`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
address            used_at
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.py", line 10, in <module>
am.ru              2014        621
    print(infile.groupby(["address", infile['used_at'].dt.year])['ID'].nunique()).reset_index(name='count')
                   2015        273
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reset_index'`